# Jmeter - running the exact number of requests within an hour with the highest defined concurrency

Tags: jmeter

I have a task to run the exact number of requests within an hour, with a given maximum number of concurrency, how do i design that with Jmeter?

```
For example:
Total number of request: 1000
Run time: 60 mins
Max Concurrency: 15
```

Meaning my script needs to reach the maximum of 15 requests at the same time at least once, and the rest can be distributed unevenly throughout an hour, and it needs to finish 1000 requests within an hour.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set the hard limit on the number of requests which JMeter will execute by using [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) in "Total Executions" mode
2. You can slow down JMeter's number of requests per minute by using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/). If you need to execute 1000 requests in 60 minutes you need to run 16.6 requests per minute, in this case they will be evenly distributed.

If your workload patterns are more complex consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

Comment: Thanks, how do I account the peak of 15 requests? I may need to reach that at least once.